# ASM or CGLIB analog for Dalvik

Tags: java, android, java-bytecode-asm, cglib

I'm looking for a CGLIB analog usable for Dalvik bytecode. Is there such library in the Android world?

Maybe, there is a way to translate CGLIB result to Davlik bytecode on-the-fly?

Answer (score 5):

Just came across this library from the Android team on google code recently:
[Dexmaker](http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/)

Seems to have potential.  This is related specifcially to an ehancement request to Android: [Dalvik Bytecode generation](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6322)

Answer (score 4):

You can try incubation ASM-subproject [asmdex](http://websvn.ow2.org/listing.php?repname=asm&path=/trunk/asmdex/). Though currently there isn't much documentation available.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net) which in its newest version supports Android.